# TensorFlow CNN some kernels not learning

Tags: tensorflow

I have an AlexNet implementation in TensorFlow which is converging, though not to the supposed loss values... I start with a learning rate of 0.01 (as stated in the paper for ILSVRC2012) and right before the first LR drop, the loss is about 6.0, where it should be around 3.0 and 3.5... now that I exported the weights for visualisation, I noticed that some of the channels in the convolutional layers are not learning... in the first layer I have 96 channels, but only 63 of them have "normal values", the remaining 33 have 0 values...

Here is an image of the kernels, each normalised to its maximum. The unlearned kernels are the ones that are "random".

[image]

Any ideias as to why? I have a dropout rate of 50% during train in the first 2 FC layers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide a link to the source code?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't show the whole code, what part do you need to see?